# I am trying to play a video from URL which is playing in VLC media player but not playing in native player i.e MPMoviePlayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, url, mpmovieplayercontroller

It is showing like this in browser,when I click on play it doesn't do anything.
But the same URL is working fine in Android native player.

[image]

Here is my code and URL of that video stored in server, format of video is MP4.

I tried with some other URLs like

```
NSURL *url=[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.ebookfrenzy.com/ios_book/movie/movie.mov"];
NSURL *urll = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"http://nordenmovil.com/urrea/InstalaciondelavaboURREAbaja.mp4"];
```

These  are working fine but below one is not working

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"http://****IP****.com:8888/alias_1440247177838"];
moviePlayer=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, self.videoPlayView.frame.size.width, self.videoPlayView.frame.size.height * (1.0f/3.0f)-20);
moviePlayer.controlStyle=MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay=YES;
[self.videoPlayView addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
[moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
```

Comment: what does this URL return? Did you try this URL in a browser or VLC player?

Comment: Yes I tried in VLC,it is working fine.

Comment: try testing this in a browser

Comment: @S1LENTWARRIOR it is not playing in browser, instead it is showing just a play icon,when I click on play even also it is not playing anything.

But in Android native player it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `MPMoviePlayer` can only play video from a direct link. (similar to the ones that you mentioned in your question.

You can either:

1. use a direct link
2. Or switch to `UIWebView` instead of `MPMoviePlayer`

You can use a `UIWebView` in following way:

```
UIWebView* webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://****IP****.com:8888/alias_1440247177838"];
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @ S1LENT WARRIOR: I tried with webview also even though it is not working.

Comment: @Santo can you share the actual URL of the video?

Comment: I cant share URL for security purpose. But don't understand why it is not playing when it can play in VLC as well as in Android.

Comment: @Santo let me know if this helps you. and i'll update my answer

Comment: ok thank you I will check once with server side and I will update my answer. Thanks bro :)